# Is a `preloaded library` warning from `rkhunter` a reason to worry?

Tags: security, rkhunter

```
[17:16:52] Checking for preloaded libraries                [ Warning ]
[17:16:53] Warning: Found preloaded shared library: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so

########

#ls /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-*
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-aarch64.so  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so      /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v8l.so
```

And I have zero idea what that means. I have installed `rkhunter` on a dirty system so the file hashes are not reliable but that doesn't sound relevant to the above warning.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a rootkit if that's what you worry about. It's a [well-known library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443273/raspberry-pi-libarmmem-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-error) injected in every process on Raspbian via `/etc/ld.so.preload`.